# How to combine scopes in Ruby on Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search, scope

I am quite new to Rails and I can't seem to get my head around this:

I have various **Projects** belonging to various **Clients**.

In my *Project* model I have two search functions:

```
scope :search_by_name, lambda { |fn| where('name LIKE ?', "%#{fn}%") }

scope :search_by_client, lambda { |fn| where('client_id LIKE ?', fn) }
```

Both seem to work. For example in the URL I can pass in this query:

```
/projects?search_by_name=fooproject
```

I can equally do this:

```
/projects?search_by_client_name=misterx
```

This will yield all the *Projects* belonging to the *Client* MisterX.

Now is there a way to *combine* these two search functions so that a query

```
/projects?search=foofoo
```

will retrieve Projects named *foofoo* as well as projects belonging to Clients named *foofoo*?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What does your controller look like?

Comment: Like this: `@projects = current_user.projects.search_by_name(params[:name]).search_by_client(params[:client])`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In SQL, you can search by multiple conditions. You have defined two scoped, and they can be chained together as follows:

```
Project.search_by_name('fooproject').search_by_client('misterx')
```

This creates the following SQL:

```
SELECT "projects".* FROM "projects" WHERE "projects".name LIKE '%fooproject%' AND "projects".client_id LIKE '%misterx'
```

The operator joining these two conditions is "AND" which means that the result would be those that meet both conditions, not either condition.

There are a few ways to retrieve projects having a certain name, or projects belonging to a client. The most simple way is to create a new scope which specifies the OR operator:

```
scope :search_by_name_or_client, lambda { |name, client| where('name LIKE ? OR client_id LIKE ?', "%#{name}%", "%#{client}%") }
```

You may also want to look at SQL UNIONs, which combines the result set of two or more select statements. ActiveRecord does not handle UNION functionality, but there are gems to extend the functionality to include this, such as https://github.com/tsmango/union

And example of writing this using the Union gem would look like this:

```
Project.union([{:conditions => ['name like ?', "%#{name}%"]}, {:conditions => ['client like ?', "%#{client}%"]}])
```

This would generate the following SQL:

```
SELECT "projects".* FROM "projects" WHERE "projects".name LIKE '%fooproject%'
UNION
SELECT "projects".* FROM "projects" WHERE "projects".client_id LIKE '%misterx'
```

More information on SQL UNIONs can be found here: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp

Comment: Hey Ben, thanks for your help. Can you tell me how to use this function in my controller then. Right now I have this but I can't get it working: `@projects = current_user.projects.search_by_name_or_client(params[:name], params[:client])`

Comment: You would define a scope in your Project class that would look like:

`scope :search_by_name_or_client, lambda {|name, client_id| where("name like ? OR client_id like ?", "%#{name}%", "%#{client_id}")`

Comment: Also in your question, you seem to be searching for client_name, but checking the client_id column. I am not sure which field you want to search. client_id is presumably a column in your projects table, meaning you don't need to join client to search by name. If client is associated data, your scope may look like this:

`scope :search_by_name_or_client, lambda {|name, client_name| where("name like ? OR clients.name like ?", "%#{name}%", "%#{client_name}").joins(:client)`

Comment: OK, working much better now. Thanks so much! It's just a shame that chaining these methods in the controller will connect them via `AND` not `OR`...

Comment: It makes sense in a way, since OR relies on two or more conditions, and the grouping cannot be represented. AND is easy, because you can keep tacking these conditions onto the end of the query. Does this answer your question? If so, do you mind marking it as the accepted answer?